# htaccess issue with multiple wordpress installed in root and subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have installed 2 wordpress site in one host. Originally I have installed it in root folder, for some reason I need to install another wordpress site separately in a subfolder which later on I will going to link it in a subdomain. While I have sucessfully Installed the new wordpress, however I have  an issue with my htacccess.

Here is my htaccess in my root

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and here is my htaccess in the subfolder

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /help
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /help/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: what do you mean by "issue"? what is happening that isn't desirable?

Comment: my root wordpress has permalinks, while accessing my subdomain site, It results 404 but the theme is applied in fact I can access my subdomain/wp-admin correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /help
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /help/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

To

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /help
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```